# Flatten Observable<Observable<Cursor>> to Observable<Cursor>

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I've an `Observable` that returns a single `Cursor` instance (`Observable<Cursor>`). I'm trying to utilize `ContentObservable.fromCursor` to obtain every cursor's row in `onNext` callback.

One of the solutions I've figured out is such construction:

```
ContentObservable.fromCursor(cursorObservable.toBlocking().first())
    .subscribe(cursor -> {
        // map to object 
        // add to outer collection
    }, e -> {}, () -> { 
        // do something with list of objects (outer collection)
    });
```

This looks rather like a hack because of `toBlocking().first()`, but it works. I don't like it because most of the processing is done in `onNext` callback and we've to create outer collection to hold the intermediate results.

I wanted to use it like this:

```
cursorObservable.map(ContentObservable::fromCursor)
    .map(fromCursor -> fromCursor.toBlocking().first())
    .map(/* map to object */)
    .toList()
    .subscribe(objects -> {
        // do something with list of objects
    }
```

This still utilizes `toBlocking().first()` and doesn't work because once the `fromCursor` observable has finished the cursor is closed so there's no way to map it to object. Is there a better way to flatten `Observable<Observable<Cursor>>` to `Observable<Cursor>`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a better way to flatten `Observable<Observable<Cursor>>` to `Observable<Cursor>`?

Yes, you can use [`Observable.concat`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#concat(rx.Observable)) method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Observable<String> observable = Observable.just("1", "2");
    final Observable<Observable<String>> nested = observable.map(value -> Observable.just(value + "1", value + "2"));
    final Observable<String> flattened = Observable.concat(nested);

    flattened.subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

**UPDATE**

There are actually some other methods to transform an `Observable<Observable<Cursor>>` to `Observable<Cursor>`:

- [Observable.concat](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#concat(rx.Observable))
- [Observable.merge](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#merge(rx.Observable))
- [Observable.switchOnNext](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#switchOnNext(rx.Observable))

Just choose one that is more appropriate to you.

**UPDATE 2**

Another solution is to modify your code a bit and use a `flatMap` operator instead of `map`:

```
cursorObservable.flatMap(ContentObservable::fromCursor)
    .map(/* map to object */)
    .toList()
    .subscribe(objects -> {
        // do something with list of objects (outer collection)
    }
```